# require.js cannot be found, keep getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I have a very simple nodeJS project that has a structure as:

```
Demo
    index.html
    server.js
    scripts
      require.js
      app.js
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/app"></script>
  <body>
    <p>Press key to continue</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const port = 5000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if ((req.url = "/")) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    fs.readFile("index.html", (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write("Error: file not found");
      } else {
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      }
    });
  }
});

server.listen(port);
console.log(`Node.js web server is running at ${port}`);
```

When I executed `node server.js`, on localhost:5000, there is a `Press key to continue` message displayed but I keep getting this error message, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and in developer console => source, `require.js` file does not have any content.

I did a bit search, and my conclusion is `require.js` file cannot be located properly. I cannot find my mistakes, can anyone help?

Comment: <script src="./scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/app"></script>
try like that

Comment: @rajanbhadauria, I had tried it before, got the same error. Tried it again just now, same result.

Comment: check this -
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

Comment: You have coded your server to do nothing unless the request path is `/`, so it won't give a response when the request path is `/scripts/require.js`

Comment: @Lennholm, thanks. That is it. I would accept your answer if you put one up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues. Firstly, you have attempted to code your server to only respond to requests where the path is `/` and nothing else. Secondly, your if statement is incorrect, you do assignment (`req.url = "/"`) when you want to compare (`req.url === "/"`).

The result is that this route handler responds to any request the same way, so when requesting `/scripts/require.js` your server actually responds with the index.html file.

You need to fix that if statement and also add another if statement that handles the request for `/scripts/require.js`.

Since you're organizing your public scripts in the `scripts` folder, I suggest making a generic handler for paths that begin with `/scripts/`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
...
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if ((req.url === "/")) {
    ...
  } else if (/^\/?scripts\//.test(req.url) && req.url.endsWith(".js")) {
    fs.readFile(req.url, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write("Error: file not found");
      } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/javascript" });
        res.write(data);
      }
      res.end();
    });
  }
});
...
```